# Redirecting /dev/null to some other device

Tags: upstart, devices, init, initramfs

Is it possible to redirect, ie create `/dev/null` as non-null device, like `/dev/console` or `/dev/stdout`? This obviously has to be done before `init` runs create creates a standard `/dev/null`. Upstart seems to dislike simple symlink to `/dev/stdout`.

Comment: `Upstart seems to dislike simple symlink` Ofcourse it does not ;) Symlinks can be created across filesystems and you do not need a lot of imagination to come up with what happens when a disc is not present when upstart needs it.

Comment: @Rinzwind: /dev/stdout is hardly on any other filesystem, but yes, symlink is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> Wikipedia
>
> [/dev/null or the null device is a special file that discards all data written to it (but reports that the write operation succeeded) and provides no data to any process that reads from it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null)

The answer is `no`: redirecting from `/dev/null` is impossible since, after `/dev/null` is done there is nothing left to redirect. You need to alter the program you want to see the messages from to echo these results to a log file before a `/dev/null` comes into play.

Comment: Please read the question again. I'm not debugging any jobs. I'm also making it clear any switch needs to be done prior running init (Upstart) which creates /dev/null IF it is not present.

Comment: Answer is still no.

Comment: Can you revise your answer then to reflect the question, and I'll then accept it (ie. I'm creating /dev/null to whatever I wish, and not trying to fix it after being created as null device.)

Comment: i think what R was saying is that if you did do this, it would create a huge security hole and probably be considered, at least at some level, malicious intent, even if it is not intended to be that way, since /dev/null is intended to discard and hide output, and sometimes it is sensitive data that should not be seen, ever... any uppity noseity programmer is going to give you a no. That does not however mean that it is impossible.. just means that it probably would be viewed in a negative light if you did. PS: i know its late but I try to put comments in where they look like they are needed :)